# Apache: Disable Cache-Control: max-age?

Tags: apache, cache-control

A book about performance reads that you should use `Expires` or `Cache-Control: max-age` but not both .

`Expires` was easy to configure on my Apache.

Now I would like to disable the unneeded `Cache-Control: max-age` but I don't how to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mention of both headers suggests that you're using `mod_expires`.
You cannot select only one header using `mod_expires`. The code that sets the headers [in `mod_expires.c`](https://github.com/apache/httpd/blob/2fb2dff3c3019bf50fee9d61ae3e756193c31ab8/modules/metadata/mod_expires.c#L432) unconditionally sets both headers to equivalent values:

```
apr_table_mergen(t, "Cache-Control",
                 apr_psprintf(r->pool, "max-age=%" APR_TIME_T_FMT,
                              apr_time_sec(expires - r->request_time)));
timestr = apr_palloc(r->pool, APR_RFC822_DATE_LEN);
apr_rfc822_date(timestr, expires);
apr_table_setn(t, "Expires", timestr);
```

However, [using `mod_header`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html#examples) may allow you to set what you want, using something like:

```
Header unset Cache-Control
```

There is a case for using both: `Cache-Control` allows much finer control than `Expires`, while `Expires` may help much older clients.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I will just continue using both.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned function can be disabled by modifying the server configurations. Firstly, you need to locate your Apache configuration files and open it in a text editor. Search for the relevant directives and change add the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Restart the system for the command to take effect.